# How to input two numbers and output their sum in SML-NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to write a sample program that input's two numbers from the user and print their sum as output in SML-NJ. The two numbers should be integers and each integer will be given in a new line. It is guaranteed that the input will be of integer type and there is no need to check it. I have installed the SML-NJ compiler and I am compiling using the ml-build command.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to input two number. I am able to print the sum but I am not able to take user input. I want to do it in a test.sml file and compile and run it. Help is appreciated @SimonShine

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't specify what kind of numbers you would like as input, how to extract the numbers from the input, or what should happen in case any errors occur, I will assume integers, one integer per line, and that nothing should happen in case any errors occur.

```
fun getInt () =
    (case TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn of
          NONE => NONE
        | SOME s => (case Int.fromString s of
                          NONE => NONE
                        | SOME n => SOME n))

fun getTwoInts () =
    (case getInt () of
          NONE => NONE
        | SOME i => (case getInt () of
                          NONE => NONE
                        | SOME j => SOME (i,j)))

fun sumAndPrintTwoInts () =
    (case getTwoInts () of
          NONE => ()
        | SOME (i,j) => print (Int.toString (i+j)))
```

But there are many ways that those functions could be structured. For example,

```
infix 3 >>=
fun NONE >>= _ = NONE
  | (SOME a) >>= f = f a

fun getInt () =
    TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn >>= Int.fromString

fun getTwoInts () =
    getInt () >>= (fn i =>
    getInt () >>= (fn j => SOME (i,j)))

fun sumAndPrintTwoInts () =
    getTwoInts () >>= (fn (i,j) => (print (Int.toString (i+j)); NONE))
```

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure questions like these deserve help, where the OP doesn't invest the slightest amount of effort in phrasing the problem. It was probably a mere copy/paste of the homework statement.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan i'm not a student for your information and i just wanted to keep the title simple and easy for you to understand.

Comment: Standard ML is among the harder languages to learn without a textbook. There is hardly enough example code. But yes, StackOverflow users should probably not be rewarded for asking bad questions. @SaiKiran: Consider reading the [guide to asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid getting your future questions downvoted.

Comment: @SaiKiran I see. Well, in its current form, the "question" reads disrespectful **to me**, because it sounds like a command. That's all.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan sorry I didn't mean to be rude or anything, I always try to keep the questions short so that it would be easy for people to read and they would help answering it without skipping it.

Comment: @SimonShine my code still has bugs. I created a structure Test =  struct and then copied the code that you gave. There were some bugs and I tried to fix it but in vain. Syntax error at EOF and syntax error after struct. I tried different ways and read about it but in vain.

Comment: @SaiKiran: Clearly you didn't read the "good questions" guide, because you just spent three lines saying "It doesn't work." Your comment suggests that you should read a textbook on SML, because you can keep asking questions like that and they're hard to answer in a comment box like this. Consider using another compiler than SML/NJ; e.g. Moscow ML, or Poly/ML. They let you evaluate .sml files without having to wrap them inside structures or provide project description files.